# Logging in with Facebook sdk4 in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, scope, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm hitting some real issues with scope. It largely has to do with the fact that I've never used PHP namespaces. I see the examples like [this one](http://metah.ch/blog/2014/05/facebook-sdk-4-0-0-for-php-a-working-sample-to-get-started/) and I can get it to work perfectly. But due to the way I built my site I'm using a lot of functions. I'd like to create a global PHP object, then call it from within functions.

I had done this using the Facebook api from 2011, which just had facebook.php, base_facebook.php and fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt, but I wanted to push forward using the latest version available.

I'm allowing access to my site with Facebook or Twitter, so a user logs in, and it checks for an active site session, and if it can't find one, it checks for an active Facebook session, which it then checks against the users database. The problem I'm hitting it accessing I can create this session in my base code, but I can't seem to access it from within the login processing function.

I've been searching, but I'm just not sure what to look for at this point. If anyone can give me a sample of how to access the Facebook objects within the function that are initialized globally, I can likely handle the rest from there.

Comment: The new SDK don't have global state of who is logged in. If you need it you need to create it yourself.

Comment: The problem I'm having though, if I want to initialize these in a global area, even just doing the includes, I am having the hardest time ever figuring out how to access them from within a function.

For example, this code should still work in a function since the object has been included in the document, $request = new FacebookRequest( $fbsession, 'GET', '/me' ); -- but I get the error: "Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRequest' not found" - I don't understand what I'm missing, but I believe it's related to the namespaces being used in this SDK, something i'm unfamiliar with

Comment: You get that error because you haven't included the file that includes FacebookRequest

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

It was a simple enough solution, just something I wasn't familiar with. When calling the object you need to express the namespace as well. So my call of

```
new FacebookRequest() - Does Not Work within a function

new Facebook\FacebookRequest() - Does Work
```

I still need to read up on this a bit, but at least I have a working solution.